# Overriding create() for class based generic views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

How can I perform some logic prior to saving a record within my generic view? I believe the actual saving logic occurs within `super().create()`.

The request within `create()` looks like this

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['5WvMZnoBMCUjmlMBaacLnx6Pxt3jUDvHWHvo90ORumYrClkebcx7NJZpmWASRIyG'], 'user': ['1'], 'address': ['3E8ociqZa9mZUSwGdSmAEMAoAxBK3FNDcd']}>
```

view

```
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some logic here prior to saving
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For instance, I would like to create the value for `balance` instead of relying on the value from the request

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=16, decimal_places=8)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=34, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You can check my answer, after you go to create method it calls perform_create internally where you will pass your request to serializer create method, If you want to change the values you can do anywhere in these 3 methods but make sure you follow the correct order. serializer.save() internally calls to create method or update method of serializer depending upon request method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flow when you are saving your request data into model
Also please check the syntax
create -> perform_create -> serializer's create back to perform create then back to create

```
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        wallet = self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(
            self.get_response_data(user),
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers,
        )


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        wallet = serializer.save(user=self.request.user) # if you want to change how you want to save from serializer to your model then you should override create method of serializer as I have shown below
        wallet.balance = 30
        wallet.save()
        return wallet


# serializers.py
class WalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wallet
        fields = "__all__"
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # here in validated data you will receive your request data after validation  If you want to discard any request value you can do here
        balance = validated_data.pop("balance", None)
        wallet = Wallet.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return wallet
```

Comment: What is recommended/preferred? Saving within the view or serializer?

Comment: It depends on your use, if you want to work on validated_data then you should use create() method of serializer and if you want to work on request.data without data validation then you can use `create` and `perform_create`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override model save method

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=16, decimal_places=8)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=34, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if not self.pk:
         #You can write own logic here
         self.balance = 10 
       super(Wallet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand your problem.

you want to override create method in generics.ListCreateAPIView.

so you have to define some method, here you want to create new record so you want to define post method and in post method you can override create method.

```
class WalletListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
   serializer_class = WalletSerializer

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

NOTE:
- as per your Wallet model address field is not blank, so you should have pass address. then run it.